# How to replace similar code in VS 2017.

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2017, notepad++, find-replace

I am replacing our logging functionality and it is taking a long time to manually go through all of the code and replace it.

Here is the current code:

**Error Messages**:

```
cLogger.LogMessage(ComponentID.ClientID, CLASS_NAME, "AddContextMenuItem", MessageType.mtErrorMessage, "Null MenuItem provided. MenuItem's status not changed");

cLogger.LogMessage(ComponentID.ClientID, CLASS_NAME, "enableDisableToolbarItem", MessageType.mtErrorMessage, "Invalid toolbaritem provided.");
```

**Exceptions**:

```
cLogger.LogMessage(ComponentID.ClientID, CLASS_NAME, "enableDisableContextMenuItem", MessageType.mtException, ex);

cLogger.LogMessage(ComponentID.ClientID, CLASS_NAME, "AddToolbarItem", MessageType.mtException, exc);
```

Is there a simple way to create a macro (never used a macro before) or power shell or notepad++ script or something else to find and replace all of these different instances so that they look like the following:

**New Error Messages**:

```
logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, CLASS_NAME + " AddContextMenuItem - Null MenuItem provided. MenuItem's status not changed");

logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, CLASS_NAME + " enableDisableToolbarItem - Invalid toolbaritem provided.");
```

and

**New Exceptions**:

```
logger.Log(LogLevel.Exception, CLASS_NAME + " enableDisableContextMenuItem - " + ex);

logger.Log(LogLevel.Exception, CLASS_NAME + " AddToolbarItem - " + exc);
```

I am replacing the code in the entire project and it will just simply take way too long to go through and manually change all of the logging code manually.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few options:

1. Regex Search & Replace in Visual Studio:

   search for the exception example

   ```
   \w+logger.LogMessage\([^,]+,([^,]+),([^,]+),[^,]+,([^\",]+)\);
   ```

   replace

   ```
   logger.Log(LogLevel.Exception, $1 + $2 + $3);
   ```
2. Use [Resharper structural Search & Replace](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Navigation_and_Search__Structural_Search_and_Replace.html)
3. Build a [CodeFix for Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/How-To-Write-a-C%23-Analyzer-and-Code-Fix)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can likely do this with a Regular Expression, easier in PowerShell perhaps than in Notepad++ or perhaps VSCode.

It's difficult to tell from your examples precisely what you are changing in each item, but the basic concept is to do the following:

1. Match the static text that establishes the type of item to change
2. Also match the variable text with wildcards (.* etc) enclosed in CAPTURING parentheses
3. Replace with new static text and 'rearranged' variable text using the $1, $2, etc backreferences to the capture groups (or $Matches[1] etc.)

If #3 is more complicated, you'll need to further alter the variable text before replacing -- this is where a script language has an advantage over a pure search and replace.

Here is a simplified example (PowerShell but similar in other langauges or editors that support Regexes) for statically replacing the "FunctionOldName" while swapping the order of Param1 and Param2 and altering the names based on the original names for these params:

```
"Function_OldName Param1 Param2" -replace 'Function_OldName\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)', 
                                          'NewFunctionName New$2Parm New$1Parm'
```

The $1 and $2 are backreferences to the "1st parens" and "2nd parens" respectively in the match string.

If you can write out clear examples showing which parts of your changed text must be matched, simply altered, rearranged, or rebuilt then it might be possible to show you some more relevant examples....

You can do this across many files with either PowerShell or the editors, but generally doing it to many files is again a bit easier in a Programming language (e.g., PowerShell.)

```
Get-ChildItem *.PS1 -recurse | ForEach-Object { 
  'Function_OldName\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)',   # your match goes here
  'NewFunctionName New$2Parm New$1Parm' # your replacement goes here
}
```